# Unhandled exception type Throwable without generic type

Tags: java, generics, java-8

The code below doesn't compile. I get Unhandled exception type `Throwable`.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();
    myResponse.getObjects().stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> SOME_EXCEPTION);
 }
```

However if I put the type object then it works fine :

```
MyResponse<Object>  myResponse = new MyResponse<>();
```

And `MyResponse` class has a list of objects :

```
private List<T> objects;
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: I think it has a little in common with raw types, reopened it.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Have you read that Q&A? This question is answered under the section [*A raw type is the erasure of that type*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: It does. `() -> SOME_EXCEPTION` is a `Supplier<SomeException>`. Once you use raw types, you live in a pre-generics world where genrics don't exist. So the Supplier basically becomes a Supplier<Throwable>. So you need to catch, because the compiler has no way to know that the exception thrown by orElseThrow is a runtime exception. Don't use raw types.

Comment: @JBNizet you're absolutely right, but eliminating raw types doesn't help if you provide a supplier of a checked exception. It guarantees only that unchecked exception suppliers won't cause a compilation error

Comment: Of course, but that's not what the OP is doing, otherwise the code wouldn't compile when he uses `MyResponse<Object>`, i.e. when he doesn't use a raw type anymore.

Comment: @JBNizet, makes sense to me now, agreed to close :)